# Connection to imap server failed on Roundcube

Tags: roundcube

I have installed Roundcube on local machine and it works fine, but with same configuration, it is not working on server. It's giving an "Connection to IMAP Server failed" error.

```
$rcmail_config['default_host'] = 'ssl://imap.gmail.com:993';
```

Log:

```
> [17-Jan-2011 03:05:06 +0400]: IMAP
> Error: Login failed for
> xxxxx@gmail.com from xxx.xxx.xx.xx.
> Could not connect to
> imap.gmail.com:143: Connection timed
> out in
> /home/xxxxx/public_html/rc/program/include/rcube_imap.php
> on line 183 (POST
> /mail/?_task=login&_action=login)
```

I'm wondering - why is it trying on port 143, when port #993 is written in config.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the configurations as follows

```
$rcmail_config['default_host'] = 'ssl://imap.gmail.com';
$rcmail_config['default_port'] = '993';
```

it should work , if not check with the below commands whether it is possible to connect to the sever through commands as shown below:

1. `ping imap.gmail.com`
2. `telnet imap.gmail.com 993` [for Windows] or `telnet imap.gmail.com:993` [for UNIX]

If you are able to get the successful output. you will be able to connect to the IMAP Gmail server via Roundcube.

Answer (score 0):

Port 993 is default for ssl://. the problem is with your server as sometime due to limited memmory by hosting provider they can't connect to gmail. I had a similar situation. I could connect to other mail server from my hosting server but not gmail. Then i switched hosting to other company and same code worked.